# Using Python to Write inside Django/HTML {Block}

Tags: python, html, django

I have a Python program that evaluates user input; for example, first name and last name.  I wanted to display to the HTML file when the names are not registered.  How do I go about displaying such information inside HTML?  The idea is to "auto-generate" the HTML page so that my views.py can display the content.

## Desired output:

#### The following name(s) are not registered:

- Name_One
- Name_Two
- Name_Three

I do know that Django has the {% block %} tag or {{ variable }} tag but I'm not sure how to use it from Python or if it's valid syntax.

**Example Python Program**

```
def checkDB ():
....
    if re.search (self.name, db):
        print ('Name exists.')
    else:
        print ('Cannot find names.')
        with open (templates/response.html', 'a') as html:
            html.write (self.name)
```

**Example HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>The following name(s) are not registered:</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>{% block content %}{% end block %}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**Update**

- Django Views will cycle through the form and get the data.  It will
  then write to a text file and then call my main () program.
- Main () will cycle through the text file and then pass individual information to the class, checkDB, where it will process the data.
- checkDB will check to see if the name exists and write to the HTML file so that the Django Views can display that error to user.

Hope this makes sense.  I'm all for a better method if you have any.

Comment: Do you intend on creating a new html each time your script runs? Or will the script run just once, record the names and put them in a static file. And then the django view will just render the static html for a particular url?

Comment: That's correct.  The program will run once and append to the existing HTML file so that Django view can display it.  I've updated the original post to be more specific but if you have a better alternative, please let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may be looking for is way to render a template as a string. With Django, you can accomplish this with the `render_to_string` function located in the template loader...

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def checkDB (self):
    ....
    if re.search (self.name, db):
        print ('Name exists.')
    else:
        return render_to_string('templates/response.html', {'name': self.name})
```

However, I'm not sure if you'll need to do anything different or special in order to use this functionality outside of the context of a Django app.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the problem I'm trying to solve.  If I just paste the checkDB () code inside my views then I can render it like you've suggested.  I just don't know if that's the "way" to go.  How would one process the formset in Django?  Is it all done in views.py?

Comment: Basically yes, you would need to process it in a view, or otherwise be able to pass a Django-compatible request object around to be able to get the post data for the formset.